# Linker error compiling with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, undefined-reference, boost-interprocess

I have written a small program that writes a boost::interprocess::container string into a shared memory and another one to read from it.

I am getting the follow linker errors:

```
g++ SharedMemTest.cpp -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a
/tmp/cc5v7WKj.o: In function `boost::interprocess::detail::mutexattr_wrapper::mutexattr_wrapper(bool)':
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC2Eb[_ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC5Eb]+0x1c): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC2Eb[_ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC5Eb]+0x31): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared'
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC2Eb[_ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperC5Eb]+0x4c): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/tmp/cc5v7WKj.o: In function `boost::interprocess::detail::mutexattr_wrapper::~mutexattr_wrapper()':
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperD2Ev[_ZN5boost12interprocess6detail17mutexattr_wrapperD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/tmp/cc5v7WKj.o: In function `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::detail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)':
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_6detail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::detail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0xe0): undefined reference to `shm_open'
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_6detail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::detail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x116): undefined reference to `shm_open'
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_6detail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::detail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x16c): undefined reference to `shm_open'
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_6detail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::detail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x1c0): undefined reference to `shm_open'
/tmp/cc5v7WKj.o: In function `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(char const*)':
SharedMemTest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object6removeEPKc[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(char const*)]+0x40): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
```

I have also tried to link with the following:

```
g++ -c SharedMemTest.cpp
g++ -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.a SharedMemTest.o -o SharedMemTest
```

But none of these commands are working. Could someone please tell me how I can get this simple example to compile?

Comment: `g++ -lpthread -lrt SharedMemTest.cpp` (include pthread and rt libraries). Have you at least tried some googling?

Comment: @Yossarian, clearly, because your recommendation does not work either. If Google had the answer to everything, we would not need SO, would we?

Comment: @czchlong : His recommendation _should_ work, but try `g++ SharedMemTest.cpp -lpthread -lrt` (order matters).

Comment: @ildjarn, thank you very much. Order does matter. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ boost libraries shared\_memory\_object undefined reference to 'shm\_open'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985236/c-boost-libraries-shared-memory-object-undefined-reference-to-shm-open)

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `-L` should be a directory, but you're putting a library filename after it. You probably meant `-l rt`. Others already suggested `-l pthread`, you could also have used `-pthread` to link to the pthreads library.