# Boost error message

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting an error message that I am not understanding when attempting to compile some code using the boost 1.55 library. At first I had a simple program that attempted to allocate a shared memory object. Ran into some errors, finally I decided to copy and paste the boost example and compile that. Got the same errors. The example code:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;

   if(argc == 1){  //Parent process
      //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
      struct shm_remove
      {
         shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
         ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      } remover;

      //Create a shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write);

      //Set size
      shm.truncate(1000);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

      //Write all the memory to 1
      std::memset(region.get_address(), 1, region.get_size());

      //Launch child process
      std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
      if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
         return 1;
   }
   else{
      //Open already created shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (open_only, "MySharedMemory", read_only);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_only);

      //Check that memory was initialized to 1
      char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < region.get_size(); ++i)
         if(*mem++ != 1)
            return 1;   //Error checking memory
   }
   return 0;
}
```

When I compile it the errors I get are:

```
g++  -D_REENTRANT -o loadfrags loadfrags.o -Lstdc++ -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
loadfrags.o: In function `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)':
loadfrags.cc:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_9ipcdetail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x105): undefined reference to `shm_open'
loadfrags.cc:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_9ipcdetail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x139): undefined reference to `shm_open'
loadfrags.cc:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_9ipcdetail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x18e): undefined reference to `shm_open'
loadfrags.cc:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object19priv_open_or_createENS0_9ipcdetail13create_enum_tEPKcNS0_6mode_tERKNS0_11permissionsE[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)]+0x1e7): undefined reference to `shm_open'
loadfrags.o: In function `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(char const*)':
loadfrags.cc:(.text._ZN5boost12interprocess20shared_memory_object6removeEPKc[boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::remove(char const*)]+0x42): undefined reference to `shm_unlink'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [loadfrags] Error 1
```

As near as I can tell the libraries are installed correctly. I was able to compile and run an anonymous shared memory object program without issue. I am not enough of a C++ programmer to quickly determine what's wrong here. My thought is that I'm missing and #include of some sort. I'd appreciate any insight/help anyone could give.

Comment: @Praetorian I looked at that question but none of the responses applied (I have since added -Lrt to the linking line).

Comment: There's a difference between `-L` and `-l`, the former is for directories where the linker will search for the libraries specified by the latter

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks. The lower case "L" did the trick.

Comment: Please improve your title so that it distinguishes this question from other questions in lists of titles.

Answer (score 4):

There are clues in the error message that this is a linking problem:

- `undefined reference to` is indicating that a needed symbol is not available when linking

and

- `ld returned 1 exit status` shows that ld (the linker) did not complete successfully.

The trick is when you see `undefined reference to <some symbol>` you need to find the library that provides the symbol and add `-l<libraryName>` to the compiler options. If the library is not in the normal locations you may need to also add `-L<PathWhereLibraryCanBeFound>`.

As indicated in the comments and as suggested in [C++ boost libraries shared_memory_object undefined reference to 'shm_open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985236/c-boost-libraries-shared-memory-object-undefined-reference-to-shm-open)  adding `-lrt` solves the problem in this case.